# Add a field in newsletter_subscriber Table in magento

Tags: magento

I wanna make a module by which i can add a field in newsletter_subscriber table in database in magento.
Although i have added a field in customer table in past but i am unable to enter the field in news letter table. It always give me error "call to undefined function addAttribute".

I have also try to use 
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup in config.xml then there is another error 'wrong entity' appear.
i am using following line to add a field.

$installer->addAttribute('newsletter/subscriber', 'city', array(
        'type'  `enter code here` => 'varchar',
        'label'     => 'City',
        'visible'   => false,
        'required'  => false
));

Please tell me where i am wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You can't add eav attribute to `newsletter_subscriber` table. On the latest magento version you should use

```
$table = $installer->getTable('newsletter_subscriber');
$table->addColumn('<field>', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'unsigned'  => true,
    'nullable'  => false,
    'primary'   => true,
));
```

Comment: i am working or magento1.6.0 and still there is error occur "Call to a member function addColumn() on a non-object"

Comment: getTable retruns table name as string

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to add a custom column to the `newsletter_subscriber` table in Magento 1.9

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$table = $this->getTable('newsletter_subscriber');

$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn(
        $table,
        '<field>', array(
            'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            'nullable'  => true,
            'after'     => null,
            'comment'   => 'Note: the comment is mandatory'
        )
    );

$installer->endSetup();
```